# How can I use PHP to get special characters from a URL? Such as %20

Tags: php, url

Lets say I have this in my URL;

```
/?utmsource=John%20Kez
```

I need to get 'John%20Kez' exactly as it is, with %20 not a space. I have tried;

```
echo $_GET['utmsource'];
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($_GET['utmsource']);
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['utmsource']);
```

All of them return 'John Kez'. How can I return 'John%20Kez'?

Comment: [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: I have this in the URL;
    
    utmsource=John%27sSource

Then I have this in the code;

    echo urlencode($_GET['utmsource']);

And that returned this;

    John%5C%27sSource

'John%20Kez' returned 'John+Kez'

Any idea why it's not returning the exact characters?

Comment: should've slapped that in the answers area @JayBlanchard *lol!* but I'm sure there's a dupe for this, somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php):

```
echo rawurlencode($_GET['utmsource']);
```

Comment: I have this in the URL;
    
    utmsource=John%27sSource

Then I have this in the code;

    echo urlencode($_GET['utmsource']);

And that returned this;

    John%5C%27sSource

'John%20Kez' returned 'John+Kez'

Any idea why it's not returning the exact characters?

Comment: From the docs: *"Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and **spaces encoded as plus (+) signs**."*

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have tried  'echo rawurlencode($_GET['utmsource']);'  and  'John%27s%20Source'  still returns  'John%5C%27s%20Source'. I can not figure out why it is picking up the extra characters or how to stop that.